# Custom file listings with icons embedded rather than custom directory listings

Tags: php, html, apache, directory

I know that I could create custom directory listings but I'd rather keep the `.htaccess` with `Options +Indexes` than have them open, for security reasons and to offer uploads.

The idea is that the page with the upload box will also have a list of the files people have uploaded.

```html
<input type="file">


<?php
$path = "/portal/campaigns/name/upload/upload/uploads/";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as &$url) {
    echo "<a href='https://example.com/portal/campaigns/name/upload/upload/uploads/".$url.">".$url."</a><br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to progress. Of course all files are within the `uploads` subdirectory and I could just type out a new link for each like I currently do, that way I can display the filename and the path so like this;

```html
<a href="https://example.com/portal/campaigns/name/upload/upload/uploads/my%20file.png">my file </a>
```

I could just do this manually but it would be good to display them automatically. If I can get help to figure this out it can then be used to automatically show user uploaded images in the gallery without me having to code for each one. This is why it can't be done with custom directory listings as it won't show the actual image. I also want this method to work first in order to have clickable links to each image too.

Literally any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. The code you provided already lists automatically all that files that are in `/portal/campaigns/name/upload/upload/uploads/`. Why would you have to do anything manually on top of that?

Comment: I was saying that manually would be an alternative. Currently, nothing is echoed by this PHP

Comment: `scandir()` needs an absolute server path, including the DOCUMENT_ROOT. For now it looks like you're just passing a path relative to document root.